# Simplifying numerical expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am needing to simplify the following numerical expression:

8 -2/3

**Here are my options:**

-4,
4,
-1/4,
1/4

I have tried everything and I'm not coming up with any of these. Please help.

Comment: google calculator says 7.33333333333  https://www.google.at/search?source=hp&q=8+-2%2F3&oq=8+-2%2F3&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2085.2085.0.5311.3.2.0.0.0.0.51.51.1.2.0....0...1.2.64.psy-ab..1.0.0.0...67.92N1nkTITvk

Comment: $8-\frac23 = \frac{24}{3} - \frac{2}{3} = \frac{22}{3}$.

Comment: Please make it more clear exactly what the original expression was. Is the fraction $-2/3$ a superscript: i.e. a little smaller than the $8$ and raised slightly above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8^(-2/3)
=2^(3*(-2/3))
=2^(-2)
=1/2^2
=1/4

Answer (score 1):

Use the hints below :

- $8=2^3$
- $(a^q)^{\frac pq}=a^p$
- $a^{-n}=\dfrac 1{a^n}$

Answer (score 1):

Either there's a typo in the book, or you haven't transcribed it correctly.

Based on the choices, the intended expression was probably 
$$8^{\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$
in which case, the simplification works out as
\begin{align*}
8^{\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)}
&=\frac
{1}
{8^
{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac
{1}
{\Bigl(8^
{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}\Bigr)^2}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac
{1}
{2^2}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac
{1}
{4}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}